# Solution to Legendre eq in trig form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

Okay I'm having a little trouble in answering this question...

[image]

so the general solution is $y(x) = AP_n(x) + BQ_n(x)$

umm then what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

When $x = cos\theta$, then $\frac{dx}{d\theta} = - sin\theta$, so the differential equation you give translates into
$$[(1-x^2)y^{'}]^{'} + 6y =0$$
So, it's a Legendre equation with $n = 2$ (as $2(2+1) = 6$). Its two linearly independent solutions are
\begin{cases}
y = 3x^2 - 1 &( = 3 \cdot P_2)
\\y = (3x^2 - 1)ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) - 6x &(= 4 \cdot Q_2)
\end{cases}
or, in terms of $\theta$,
\begin{cases}
y = 3cos^2\theta - 1
\\y = (3cos^2\theta - 1)ln(\frac{1+cos\theta}{1-cos\theta}) - 6cos\theta
\end{cases}
so the solution is
$$y = A(3cos^2\theta - 1) + B\left((3cos^2\theta - 1)ln(\frac{1+cos\theta}{1-cos\theta}) - 6cos\theta\right)$$